# JUnit5 tests work fine with maven but not when run through Eclipse, "No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'."

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit5

I'm getting a pop-up window with title "Could not run test" and message "No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'." when I try to run JUnit 5 tests with Eclipse via `Run As > JUnit Test`.

I have two test-related files. One is a test suite:

```
...

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectPackages;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectPackages("com.foo.stufftotest")

public class TestSuite {
    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup() {
        ...
```

The other contains the "actual" tests:

```
package com.foo.stufftotest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.foo.TestSuite;
import com.foo.business.mechanics.LogicStuff1;

public class BusinessTest {
    @Test
    public void testLogic1() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogic2() {
        ...
    }

    ...
```

All the `testLogicN()` methods depend on setup stuff done in `TestSuite.setup()`. If `setup()` doesn't run, there are a lot of null values, and it's no surprise that things fail. When I try to run JUnit from the *project*'s context menu, all the tests are triggered and they all fail; the suite doesn't seem to be recognized. When I try to run JUnit specifically from `TestSuite.java`'s context menu, I end up with the error I mentioned at the top of the question.

However, when I run `maven test` on the project, the suite **is** triggered properly, and all the tests pass. Therefore, the code itself doesn't seem to be the problem.

I don't remember having this issue with JUnit 4, although I never used JUnit 4 with this particular project.

Am I using Eclipse wrong, or am I using JUnit5 wrong? What's the fix here?

Comment: In class `BusinessTest`: what `@Test` do you import? JUnit 4 or 5? What happens when you launch this class in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm using the JUnit5 `@Test`; I've edited to show this. When I launch the test case file directly, I get all failures, which is the expected behavior because the tests depend on the setup that happens in the suite file.

Comment: Does Eclipse execute tests, when you choose the "JUnit 4 Runner"? Your `TestSuite` looks like a JUnit 4 class.

Comment: Hm, okay. I intended to write JUnit5 tests, but worth a shot for diagnostic purposes. I just tried explicitly forcing it to run with the JUnit 4 runner. I did not get the "no tests found" error, but I did get the all-tests-failed-due-to-null-values situation that results from the suite methods not triggering.

Answer (score 14):

I encountered the same issue in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1 despite the fact that my unit tests were properly annotated with `org.junit.jupiter`.

I used the `Maven > Update Project` and selected `Update project configuration from pom.xml` but that did nothing even though I thought it would pick up the fact that I had JUnit5 dependencies in the pom.

My solution:

1. Open `Java Build Path`, select `Libraries` tab and `Add Library`.
2. Select `JUnit`.
3. Select `JUnit5` for JUnit library version.

Once added I was able to manually execute tests from Eclipse. However I'm still not certain why this was not added automatically.

Comment: It worked for me. I was using the Spring Tool Suite 4 Version: 4.0.0.RELEASE. However, wondering why I don't get the run as Junit Test option when I select the test class. Whereas, I get these options at project level or at the test package level  (`src/test/java`) as well. Not a showstopper but not able to figure out.

Comment: for those who are searching where Java Build Path is: right click project -> properties -> Java Build Path

Answer (score 3):

> I'm getting a pop-up window with title "Could not run test" and message "No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'." when I try to run JUnit 5 tests with Eclipse via `Run As > JUnit Test`.

That's because `TestSuite` is in fact not a JUnit 5 test class. Since it is annotated with `@RunWith` (from JUnit 4) it is a JUnit 4 test class. To avoid the pop-up window in Eclipse, simply click on "Run Configurations" and select JUnit 4 instead of JUnit 5 for running the test class.

The other issue you have is that `@BeforeAll` is an annotation from JUnit Jupiter. Thus, it is simply not supported in a class annotated with `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` (unless that class also happens to contain `@Test` methods for JUnit Jupiter). Thus you will have to find an alternative approach to executing your "set up" code.